# How to add a testcase to a particular Plan ID & suiteID through restassured or from Postman in AzureTestPlan

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, rest-assured-jsonpath

Trying to add a testcase to a particular suiteID in AzureTestPlan

```
 try{
        String orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}";
        String personalAccessToken = "{xxx}";
        String testPlanId = "2897";
        String testSuiteId = "2899";
        String workItemTitle = "TestCaseAut";
        String workItemDescription = "New case";
        String auth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((":" + token).getBytes());
        String authHeader = "Basic " + auth;

        String createWorkItemUrl = orgUrl + "/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version=6.1-preview.1";

        String workItemData = "{\"fields\":{\"Sysytem.Title\": \"" + workItemTitle + "\", \"System.Description\": \"" + workItemDescription + "\", \"System.WorkItemType\": \"Test Case\", \"EAI Code\":\"{xxx}\", \"Area\":\"{path}\", \"Iteration\":\"{path}\"}}";

        HttpRequest createWorkItemRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(createWorkItemUrl))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(workItemData))
                .header("Authorization", authHeader)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

        HttpResponse<String> createWorkItemResponse = httpClient.send(createWorkItemRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        String workItemId = createWorkItemResponse.body().split(":")[2].split(",")[0];

        String addTestCaseUrl = orgUrl + "/_apis/testplan/plans/" + testPlanId + "/suites/" + testSuiteId + "/testcases/add?api-version=6.1-preview.1";

        String addTestCaseData = "{\"suiteType\": \"StaticTestSuite\", \"testCaseIds\": [" + workItemId + "]}";

        HttpRequest addTestCaseRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(addTestCaseUrl))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(addTestCaseData))
                .header("Authorization", authHeader)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> addTestCaseResponse = httpClient.send(addTestCaseRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println("Tc Added");
    }

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not created");
        }
```

With the above code getting as Tc Added. But in actual there was no test case added to the particular suiteID in the Azure Testplan.

Answer (score 0):

***According to this [Test Suites API1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-suites?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and [Test Case API2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-cases?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), You can only add existing **`TestCaseID`** while adding the suite and there's no option to create new TestCase with API.***

I tried using below code to create **`Test Suite`**:-

```java
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.Base64;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/ORGNAME/ProjName";
            String personalAccessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxjh7q";
            String planId = "29416";
            String suiteId = "29417";
            String workItemType = "TestSuite";
            String workItemTitle = "NewTestSuite";
            String workItemDescription = "Description";

            String token = personalAccessToken;
            String auth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((":" + token).getBytes());
            String authHeader = "Basic " + auth;

            // Create Test Suite
            String createSuiteUrl = orgUrl + "/_apis/test/Plans/" + planId + "/suites/" + suiteId + "?api-version=5.0";
            String createSuiteData = "{\"suiteType\":\"StaticTestSuite\",\"name\":\"" + workItemTitle + "\",\"parentId\":" + planId + "}";
            HttpRequest createSuiteRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(createSuiteUrl))
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(createSuiteData))
                    .header("Authorization", authHeader)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpResponse<String> createSuiteResponse = httpClient.send(createSuiteRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            if (createSuiteResponse.statusCode() == 200) {
                System.out.println("Test suite created successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error creating test suite: " + createSuiteResponse.body());
                return;
            }

            // Parse the response to get the suite ID if needed
            String suiteIdFromResponse = "Parse from createSuiteResponse";

            // Create Work Item
            String createWorkItemUrl = orgUrl + "/_apis/wit/workitems/" + workItemType + "?api-version=7.1-preview.3";
            String createWorkItemData = "{\"fields\":{\"System.Title\":\"" + workItemTitle + "\",\"System.Description\":\"" + workItemDescription + "\",\"System.AreaPath\":\"{project}\",\"System.IterationPath\":\"{project}\"}}";
            HttpRequest createWorkItemRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(createWorkItemUrl))
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(createWorkItemData))
                    .header("Authorization", authHeader)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();

            HttpResponse<String> createWorkItemResponse = httpClient.send(createWorkItemRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            if (createWorkItemResponse.statusCode() == 200) {
                System.out.println("Work item created successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error creating work item: " + createWorkItemResponse.body());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***Now, I added one Test Case manually and used it to Create the Test Suite:-***

```java
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AzureDevopsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/ORGNAME/PROJNAME";
            String personalAccessToken = "uxxxxxxxxxgsbhijh7q";
            String planId = "29416";
            String suiteId = "29424";
            String testCaseId = "29426"; // ID of the existing test case
            String workItemType = "TestSuite2";
            String workItemTitle = "NewTestSuite2";
            String workItemDescription = "Description";

            String token = personalAccessToken;
            String auth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((":" + token).getBytes());
            String authHeader = "Basic " + auth;

            // Create Test Suite
            String createSuiteUrl = orgUrl + "/_apis/test/Plans/" + planId + "/suites/" + suiteId + "?api-version=5.0";
            String createSuiteData = "{\"suiteType\":\"StaticTestSuite\",\"name\":\"" + workItemTitle + "\",\"parentId\":" + planId + "}";
            HttpRequest createSuiteRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(createSuiteUrl))
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(createSuiteData))
                    .header("Authorization", authHeader)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpResponse<String> createSuiteResponse = httpClient.send(createSuiteRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            if (createSuiteResponse.statusCode() == 200) {
                System.out.println("Test suite created successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error creating test suite: " + createSuiteResponse.body());
                return;
            }

            // Create Work Item (Test Case)
            String createWorkItemUrl = orgUrl + "/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version=7.1-preview.3";
            String createWorkItemData = "{\"fields\":{\"System.Title\":\"" + workItemTitle + "\",\"System.Description\":\"" + workItemDescription + "\",\"System.WorkItemType\":\"Test Case\"}}";
            HttpRequest createWorkItemRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(createWorkItemUrl))
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(createWorkItemData))
                    .header("Authorization", authHeader)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();

            HttpResponse<String> createWorkItemResponse = httpClient.send(createWorkItemRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            if (createWorkItemResponse.statusCode() == 200) {
                System.out.println("Work item (test case) created successfully.");
                // Parse the response to get the work item ID
                String workItemId = "Parse from createWorkItemResponse";

                // Add Test Case to Test Suite
                String addTestCaseUrl = orgUrl + "/_apis/test/Plans/" + planId + "/suites/" + suiteId + "/testcases/" + testCaseId + "?api-version=5.0";
                HttpRequest addTestCaseRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                        .uri(URI.create(addTestCaseUrl))
                        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                        .header("Authorization", authHeader)
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .build();

                HttpResponse<String> addTestCaseResponse = httpClient.send(addTestCaseRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

                if (addTestCaseResponse.statusCode() == 204) {
                    System.out.println("Test case added to test suite successfully.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error adding test case to test suite: " + addTestCaseResponse.body());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error creating work item (test case): " + createWorkItemResponse.body());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***You can retrieve the  existing `TestCaseID` by using the code below:-***

```java
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AzureDevOpsTest3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String organization = "ORGNAME"; // Update with your organization name
            String project = "PROJNAME"; // Update with your project name
            String planId = "29416"; // Update with your planId
            String suiteId = "29424"; // Update with your suiteId
            String personalAccessToken = "uvlywjxxxxxxxxxxxxcgsbhijh7q"; // Update with your personal access token
            String apiVersion = "5.0";

            String apiUrl = String.format("https://dev.azure.com/%s/%s/_apis/test/Plans/%s/suites/%s/testcases?api-version=%s",
                    organization, project, planId, suiteId, apiVersion);

            String token = personalAccessToken;
            String auth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((token + ":").getBytes());
            String authHeader = "Basic " + auth;

            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(apiUrl))
                    .header("Authorization", authHeader)
                    .build();

            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
                System.out.println("Response: " + response.body());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: " + response.statusCode() + " - " + response.body());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]